# WPF Tree View with Hierarchical data template and multi types

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a tree view create using HierarchicalDataTemplate has you can see in the code below :

```
  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllFolders}" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged"/>
```

And

```
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Folder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tools}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=icon}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Tool}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

It works well but now I need to add an other type of objects in folders to make tree view like this :

- Folder 1
- Folder 2

  - Tools

    - Tool 1
    - Tool 2
  - Locations

    - Location 1
    - Location 2
- Folder 3

The Tools and Locations has to use differents DataTemplate. They are both IList contains in Folder Class (`IList<Tool>` and `IList<Location>`).

Is it even possible to do it ? 
How can I achieve that ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that if you do one of the following options:

1) Use a collection property of type `ObservableCollection<object>` so that you can add any object types into it.

2) Define an interface or base class that the `Folder` and `Tool` classes implement (or extend) and then use a collection property of the type `ObservableCollection<YourInterface>` or `ObservableCollection<YourBaseClass>` so that you can add any object types into it.

Then, define as many `DataTemplate`s as you need, but *don't* set any `x:Key` directives on them. In this way, they will all be applied explicitly by the Framework when it comes across the different objects from the collection.

---

UPDATE >>>

Looking again at your desired folder structure, it appears that you have only one type as top level nodes, with the `Tool` and `Location` objects being children of the `Folder` objects. If that is so, then you can just use a collection of `Folder` objects as long as the `Folder` class has collection properties named `Folders` and `Locations`.

In that case, you can just supply a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for those two types as well as for the `Folder` class.

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

You can just define more `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s, one for the `Tool` and one for the `Location` classes... as long as you *don't* provide the `x:Key` directive, they will be applied implicitly by the Framework:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Tool}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tools}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=icon}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Location}" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=icon}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

However, to do this, you'd need to change the collection in the `Folder` class as stated above so that you could add both the top level `Tool` and `Location` objects in there together. If those top level objects are just 'folders' for the actual items, then you may as well remove them because they are making your code much trickier.

Comment: Thanks but, and tell me if I'm wrong, with this solution the two types (tools and locations) will be mixed. Even if I sort the collection i'll never be able to expand only one type in the tree view, right ?

Comment: Your update describe pretty well what I want to do. But the main issue is how to technicaly create the hierarchical datatemplate. It can only has one ItemsSource.